# Javascript for loop: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined

Tags: javascript, loops

```
    var volunteerOpp = [];
    var index = 0;
    function getData() {
        volunteerOpp[index] = {
            userName: $("#name").val(),
            companyName: $("#compName").val(),
            category: $("#category").val(),
            details: $("#details").val()
        };
        index ++;

    function clueless() {
    //alert("2");
        var temp = localStorage.getItem("volunteerOpp");
    var newObject = JSON.parse(temp);
        $('#name').text(newObject.userName);   
        $('#compName').text(newObject.companyName); 
        $('#category').text(newObject.category); 
        $('#details').text(newObject.details); 

    var getData="run";
     for(var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
         //var+=object[i].field + "<br>";
         getData +=volunteerOpp[0].details + "<br>";
         alert("3");
         //dumb += userName[0] + "<br>"; 
         //text += volunteerOpp[1] + "<br>"; 
         //text += volunteerOpp[2] + "<br>"; 
         //text += volunteerOpp[3] + "<br>"; 
         //text += volunteerOpp[4] + "<br>"; 
     }

     //$("id").html(var);
```

What's wrong with the code?
I getting an undefined element.
I'm not sure what's wrong, since its showing undefined elements.
It's really confusing, I know, but it won't show my arrays in the page.

Comment: `volunteerOpp[0]` must be `undefined`...

Comment: Why would it be that?

Comment: You can answer that question better than I can...

Comment: Is `volunteerOpp` defined in the same scope?

Comment: yes, volunteeropp is the variable.

Comment: It may be the variable but I don't see it defined anywhere in the code you posted...

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually running your getData function. Until you call getData(), volunteerOpp is equal to an empty array. call `getData()` and change `var getData="run"` to something else because you're replacing that entire function with the string "run".

Comment: Soo, do I just add call getData() in my javascript? And what could I change  var getData="run" to?

Comment: Yeah before you try to access volunteerOpp[0], you need to getData(). What do you want your final result to look like?